# XSLT - how to conditionally group elements using template match

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's an example of my current XML:

```
<A>1</A>
<B>abc</B>
<A>1</A>
<B>def</B>
<A>2</A>
<B>ghi</B>
<B>jkl</B>
<A>3</A>
<B>012</B>
```

So I have XSLT that I'm using to get rid of the duplicate  values, which is good and working:

```
<xsl:template match="A[preceding-sibling::A = current()]"/>
```

However, my next step is that I'm looking to wrap each group of elements that have the same A value using XSLT, e.g.:

```
<GROUP>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>abc</B>
  <B>def</B>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
  <A>2</A>
  <B>ghi</B>
  <B>jkl</B>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
  <A>3</A>
  <B>012</B>
</GROUP>
```

I'm stuck on this and can definitely use some help on this. I'm trying to use following-sibling and preceding-sibling but seem to be getting stuck. Any tips and/or help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My processor supports XSLT 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Grouping is very different for XSLT 1.0 vs. XSLT 2.0 or higher. Which version does your processor support?

Comment: Ah right - it supports XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 (in addition to 1.0 of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using keys you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="a" match="A" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="b" match="B" use="preceding-sibling::A[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="A[not(key('a', .)[1] is .)] | B"/>

  <xsl:template match="A[key('a', .)[1] is .]">
      <GROUP>
          <xsl:copy-of select="., key('b', .)"/>
      </GROUP>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in XSLT 2 or 3 (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mY/) and

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="a" match="A" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="b" match="B" use="preceding-sibling::A[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="A[not(generate-id(key('a', .)[1]) = generate-id())] | B"/>

  <xsl:template match="A[generate-id(key('a', .)[1]) = generate-id()]">
      <GROUP>
          <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('b', .)"/>
      </GROUP>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in XSLT 1 (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mY/1)

So that is basically meant to use template matching as in your subject, in general in XSLT 2/3 `for-each-group group-starting-with / group-by` are the grouping tools.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, your way of finding distinct values of A may be working, but it is not a good method - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Now, assuming you are limited to XSLT 1.0, here's how you could extend the Muenchian method to your case:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>abc</B>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>def</B>
    <A>2</A>
    <B>ghi</B>
    <B>jkl</B>
    <A>3</A>
    <B>012</B>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="a" match="A" use="." />
<xsl:key name="b" match="B" use="preceding-sibling::A[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <!-- a group for each distinct value of A -->
        <xsl:for-each select="A[count(. | key('a', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <GROUP>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <!-- get the B's associated with this value -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('b', .)"/>
            </GROUP>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <GROUP>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>abc</B>
    <B>def</B>
  </GROUP>
  <GROUP>
    <A>2</A>
    <B>ghi</B>
    <B>jkl</B>
  </GROUP>
  <GROUP>
    <A>3</A>
    <B>012</B>
  </GROUP>
</output>
```

---

IN XSLT 2.0 this could be reduced to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="b" match="B" use="preceding-sibling::A[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="A"  group-by=".">
            <GROUP>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('b', .)"/>
            </GROUP>    
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```